Given powers of tau ; the veryfying and the proving key, how can I find the point [f] resulting from the trusted setup in Groth16?
For each circuits, Groth16 requires to compute a point $f$ such as $f=s×G$. While revealing the scalar $s$ used for computing $f$ would allow to produce fake proofs, $f$ can be exposed to the public.
But how to retrieve the point $f$ for a given circuit as a circuit user ? In which parameter ? The circuit in question is created using the circom prover and I m intersted in forging public Inputs.

I’ve also a obscure 11Mb param file which is the result of the computations in the trusted setup ceremony. It definitely doesn’t allow to retrieve the scalar, but I don’t know how to get $f$ from it.
